# How to JOIN hundreds of Spark dataframes efficiently?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

TL;DR;

> “What is the most optimal way of joining thousands of Spark
>   dataframes? Can we parallelize this join? Since both do not work for
>   me.”

I am trying to join thousands of single column dataframes (with a PK col for join) and then persisting the result DF to Snowflake.

The join operation by looping around 400 (5m x 2) such dataframes is taking over 3 hours to complete on a standalone 32core/350g Spark cluster, which I think shouldn't matter because of the pushdown. After all, shouldn't all Spark be doing is build the DAG for lazy evaluation?

Here is my Spark config:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("JoinTest")\
    .config("spark.master","spark://localhost:7077")\
    .config("spark.ui.port", 8050)\
    .config("spark.jars", "../drivers/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.5.2-spark_2.4.jar,../drivers/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.1.jar")\
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "100g")\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", 0)\
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "64g")\
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "6")\
    .config("spark.executor.cores","4") \
    .config("spark.cores.max", "32")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

And the JOIN loop:

```
def combine_spark_results(results, joinKey):
    # Extract first to get going
    # TODO: validations
    resultsDF = results[0]
    i = len(results)

    print("Joining Spark DFs..")
    for result in results[1:]:
        print(i, end=" ", flush=True)
        i -= 1
        resultsDF = resultsDF.join(result, joinKey, 'outer')

    return resultsDF
```

I considered parallelizing the joins in a merge-sort fashion using starmapasync() however, the issue is, a Spark DF cannot be returned from another thread. I also considered broadcasting the main dataframe from which all joinable single-col dataframes were created,

```
spark.sparkContext.broadcast(data)
```

but that throws the same error as attempting to return a joined DF from another thread, viz.

> PicklingError: Could not serialize broadcast: Py4JError: An error
>   occurred while calling o3897.**getstate**. Trace: py4j.Py4JException:
>   Method **getstate**([]) does not exist

How can I solve this problem?

Please feel free to ask if you need any more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe just out of curiosity: is this data coming really from different data frames? Can it be loaded as one long df then grouped/pivoted? Maybe that's worth trying

Comment: Is your join condition associative? If Yes, you could join the data frames in pairs till you get the final one. It is like traversing a binary tree starting from the leafs

Comment: and I would support @ernest_k comment and think of concatenating and later grouping VS 400x join

Comment: @Egor123, yes, the individual dataframes are independent. Sure, I can try writing a recursive DFS style join; just that it is not really a tree. Do you suggest I simulate (force) a tree out of the list using indexing or the like?

Comment: @ernest_k, sure that sounds viable. And if I understand you correctly, should just append everything with respective unique identifiers per DF to help pivot later, right?

Comment: @Vaibhav, for illustrative purposes, let's replace `Dataframe` Join operation with numeric `+` (addition). You could simply do `((1+2)+3)+4`. But there is a better option. Since `+` is associative, you can do `((1+2)+(3+4))`. The advantage of the latter is the fact that `(1+2)` and `3+4` can be executed in parallel.

Comment: @Egor123, yes, I'm testing pairwise UnionAll instead of Join. That seems to be running faster. However, writing the result back to Snowflake (with pushdown) is taking 6.2 hrs. Which I guess is a separate issue for me to investigate.

Comment: Well it's basically this mammoth DAG that Spark is creating with 10656 tasks, when executing the write (or even a count() for that matter). So basically, it takes 23 mins to run the whole notebook, and 6.2 hrs to write the resultDF to SF. Not sure how to further optimize. Any help from Spark connoisseurs?